# dockerfile build cache permission issue

Tags: docker, go, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm building a container using a binary like this:

Basically the container will run an executable go program.

```
FROM myrepo/ubi8/go-toolset:latest AS build

COPY --chown=1001:0 . /build

 RUN cd /build && \
    go env -w GO111MODULE=auto && \
    go build

#---------------------------------------------------------------
FROM myrepo/ubi8/ubi-minimal:latest AS runtime

RUN microdnf update -y --nodocs && microdnf clean all && \
    microdnf install go -y && \
    microdnf install cronie -y && \
    groupadd -g 1000 usercontainer && adduser -u 1000 -g usercontainer usercontainer && chmod 755 /home/usercontainer && \
    microdnf clean all

ENV XDG_CACHE_HOME=/home/usercontainer/.cache

COPY executable.go /tmp/executable.go

RUN chmod 0555 /tmp/executable.go

USER usercontainer
WORKDIR /home/usercontainer
```

However, when running the container in Jenkins I'm getting this error:

```
failed to initialize build cache at /.cache/go-build: mkdir /.cache: permission denied
```

When running the container manually in a kubernetes deployment I'm not getting any issue but Jenkins is throwing this error and I can see the pod in CrashLoopBackOff and the container is showing the previous permissions issue.

Also, I'm not sure if I'm building the container correctly. Maybe I need to include the executable go program in the binary and later create the runtime?

Any clear example would be appreciated.

Comment: Please trim this down to a [mcve]. Do the lines in the Dockerfile make any difference, or could it just be a single `RUN echo hello world>hello` that triggers it? If this only happens in Jenkins, what's the configuration there?

Comment: I will try to reduce the the docker file to a minimum reproducible example. I am wondering if the issue is related when i'm copying the executable oprogram in the runtime instead to the binary. Also, there is no any special cnfiguration in Jenkins, the deployment is working fine without this new container. Looks like it is a golang code and Jenkins is creating some kind of cache folder and has no permissions on it.

Comment: What is the `CMD` of the final image?  Do you ever `COPY --from=build /build/the-binary` into the final image?  (You should not need the Go tool chain nor the source code to actually run the binary, and that might avoid problems around a `.cache` directory.)

Comment: @DavidMaze the CMD is basically a command  "go run /tmp/executable.go" in the kubernetes deployment file. I did not do that "COPY --from=build /build/the-binary" May you please put in an example base on my code what would you do and why? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go is a compiled language, which means that you don't actually need the `go` tool to run a Go program.  In a Docker context, a typical setup is to use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to compile an application, and then copy the built application into a final image that runs it.  The final image doesn't need the Go toolchain or the source code, just the compiled binary.

I might rewrite the final stage as:

```bash
FROM myrepo/ubi8/go-toolset:latest AS build
# ... as you have it now ...

FROM myrepo/ubi8/ubi-minimal:latest AS runtime

# Do not install `go` in this sequence
RUN microdnf update -y --nodocs && 
    microdnf install cronie -y && \
    microdnf clean all

# Create a non-root user, but not a home directory;
# specific uid/gid doesn't matter
RUN adduser --system usercontainer

# Get the built binary out of the first container
# and put it somewhere in $PATH
COPY --from=build /build/build /usr/local/bin/myapp

# Switch to a non-root user and explain how to run the container
USER usercontainer
CMD ["myapp"]
```

This sequence doesn't use `go run` or use any `go` command in the final image, which hopefully gets around the issue of needing a `$HOME/.cache` directory.  (It will also give you a smaller container and faster startup time.)

Comment: Great explanation. Let me check it out today. Thanks.

Comment: I tried with the new approach but the pod is in CrashLoopBackOff and cannot se anything clear from the logs. I mean now it does not say anything about .cache permissions issue but it is not up/running. Is it normal that when I run a  locally with that image and "cat myapp.go" I can see just a binary right? "zTX&b�O�N���;��Lwhe=k��w��_c���Ѥ�q��G..."

Comment: You shouldn't have a `*.go` file in the final image; in this sample Dockerfile, `/usr/local/bin/myapp` will be a compiled binary, yes.  Debugging it locally in plain Docker will be easier than trying to diagnose your Kubernetes setup.

Comment: My application is getting information about some environment variables that I pass to the final container. Even if the application is a binary will be able to get the environment variables that I pass through a configmap?

Comment: Yes, this works fine.  (You can experiment with the binary executable `/usr/bin/env` which prints out its environment if run with no arguments.)

Comment: The env vars are definitely there. However, I'm not sure if the program is running after the command "CMD ["myapp"]" At least, it's not sending any api calls to the second container. I will continue testing it. Also, I need to keep the container running with "command: bash -c "while true; do echo hello; sleep 10; done" in docker compose if not doing like this the container is getting restarted all the time. So I'm not sure if the executable is running propertly.

Comment: What does the Go program do?  You should never need to "keep the container running", and that `command:` runs _instead of_ the `CMD ["myapp"]`.  So long as the Go program is still running the container will be too, and if and when the Go program exits the container will stop as well (this is what you generally want).